# How does numpy.dot function work?

Tags: numpy

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
b = np.array([5, 6])
a.dot(b)
b.dot(a)
```

What happens for *a.dot(b)* and *b.dot(a)*? For matrix mutiplication, *a.dot(b)* should be illegal.

Comment: `dot` documentation describes the special handling of 1d arrays.  That is allows you use `b.dot(b)`, the inner product.

Comment: `b.dot(b)` is inner product, but `a.dot(b)` and `b.dot(a)` are matrix multiplication.

Comment: `b` is 1d, so not a matrix, or row/column vector (or is it)?  How `a.dot(b)` works might be best explained with Einstein notation:  `np.einsum('ij,j->j', a, b)`.  Or it could be described as the .dot product of each row of `a` with `b`. `a.dot(np.array([[5,6]]))` (a (1,2) array) does produce an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this setup, `b.dot(a)` is equivalent to `b.T.dot(a)`; indeed, `b` and `b.T` happen to have the same shape, so even though the notation makes it looks like `b` is a row vector, it really isn't. We can, however, redefine it to behave explicitly as a row vector, in which case the operation fails as expected:

```
In [25]: b.dot(a)
Out[25]: array([23, 34])

In [26]: b.T.dot(a)
Out[26]: array([23, 34])

In [30]: b.shape
Out[30]: (2,)

In [31]: b.T.shape
Out[31]: (2,)

In [27]: c = b.reshape((1, 2))

In [28]: c.dot(a)
Out[28]: array([[23, 34]])

In [29]: a.dot(c)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-5d91888f8066> in <module>()
----> 1 a.dot(c)

ValueError: shapes (2,2) and (1,2) not aligned: 2 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)
```